# summary column in ssrs2005 matrix

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs

Hi I create a monthly sale report. there is a week-to-date column at the end of each week, then the end of report, I need to a month-to-date column. The the column will display date and the row will display items. I use SSRS2005 Matrix to do it. I create 8 columns (monday to Sunday, plus WTD) to do it. But I do not have any idea how to solve this MTD column. 
Anyone has idea? Thanks in Advance.